# Fuzzy search of a global list in a FIELD azure

Tags: xml, azure, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to implement a fuzzy search to be used in a WITD my company uses for logging support tickets. Currently all values in the pick list come from a customer list stored in a separate file. When a user types into the text box, it only matches with items that start with the entered string. An example of this is below. When I type in "4sight" it matches with list items that begin with that phrase.

[Customer list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waJdR.png)

```
<FIELD name="Customer" refname="GlobalList.Customer" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>The customer with which this support ticket is associated</HELPTEXT>
    <REQUIRED />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <GLOBALLIST name="CustomerList" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

However when I type in "Birm", it does not match with anything, as shown below:

[Searching for a substring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hviPR.png)

The customer list contains a complete list of opticians that we provide our service too. The format is usually COMPANYNAME/LOCATION.

Is this method of searching unavoidable in TFS or are there some workarounds? It would be very useful in my place of work as opticians often go by multiple names, and often these aren't what occurs first in the list item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this kind of fuzzy search is not supported in TFS/Azure Devops Services.

The possible workaround is to develop a [workitem extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure-devops-2019) to implement your own fuzzy search method for the Field. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops-2019) to find more about Develop extensions for Azure DevOps Services.

You can click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to submit a feature request to microsoft development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature in the feature sprint.